# Using aggregate in lead()- SQL window

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to get the folliwng names as well as a column summarizing the payment + the 2 consecutive payments for the customer, listed chronologically.

First time using the lead funciton, and managed to make it work, but with the sum() I get an error:
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "p.payment_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
Position: 11

```
select 
    p.payment_id,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    p.amount,
    lead(sum(amount),3)over(partition by p.payment_id  order by amount)as sum_pay
from payment p
left join customer c on c.customer_id = p.customer_id;
```

Can anyone give any tips as to where the problem lies?
p.id   c.id s.id r.id   amount      payment_date
17503   341 2   1520    7.99    2007-02-15 22:25:46.996
17504   341 1   1778    1.99    2007-02-16 17:23:14.996
17505   341 1   1849    7.99    2007-02-16 22:41:45.996
17506   341 2   2829    2.99    2007-02-19 19:39:56.996
17507   341 2   3130    7.99    2007-02-20 17:31:48.996
17508   341 1   3382    5.99    2007-02-21 12:33:49.996
17509   342 2   2190    5.99    2007-02-17 23:58:17.996
17510   342 1   2914    5.99    2007-02-20 02:11:44.996
17511   342 1   3081    2.99    2007-02-20 13:57:39.996
17512   343 2   1547    4.99    2007-02-16 00:10:50.996
17513   343 1   1564    6.99    2007-02-16 01:15:33.996
17514   343 2   1879    0.99    2007-02-17 01:26:00.996
17515   343 2   1922    0.99    2007-02-17 04:32:51.996
17516   343 2   2461    6.99    2007-02-18 18:26:38.996

Trying to get an additional row of customer and sum payment + 2 consecutive payments

Comment: Sample data would help to explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Problem is in sum inside lead... what kind of sum you want to have ? 3 last payments from customer ?

Comment: Looks a bit off with that data sample but at least hope its easier to understand now

Comment: Please format your sample data (see [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for how to formatted text, and post table definition (ddl script) also as text - **no images**.  Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14v). Finally. post, again as formatted text, the expected output of your sample data.

Comment: When a payment id is unique, there is no point in selecting the third payment using LEAD(): it’s always NULL. Or do you want to partition by customer_id? If so, that would make the LEFT you a little strange, an INNER JOIN would make more sense